# pandas, assign multiple column values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have user data in a df_user : only 1 row

```
user_id, age, height, item_id, item_height
1, 11, 15, 2, 3
```

I have df with same columns

```
user_id, age, height, item_id, item_height
2, 22, 33, 3, 4
5, 22, 33, 5, 4
```

Now I want to assign some columns (user_id, age, height) of `df` using the values of `df_user`

so the result would be

```
user_id, age, height, item_id, item_height
1, 11, 15, 3, 4
1, 11, 15, 5, 4
```

I'm currently thinking of the following, are their better one?

```
df = df.assign(user_id=df_user.user_id.values, age=df_user.age.values, height=df_user.height.values)
```

Mainly, it's tedious to type those when you have more columns to copy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create `Series` by [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions by columns names and [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions:

```
L = ['user_id', 'age', 'height']
df1 = df.assign(**df_user.iloc[0, df_user.columns.get_indexer(L)])
```

Or is possible use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by labels:

```
L = ['user_id', 'age', 'height']
#if index is 0
#df1 = df.assign(**df_user.loc[0, L])
#general index
df1 = df.assign(**df_user.loc[df_user.index[0], L])
```

---

```
print (df1)
   user_id  age  height  item_id  item_height
0        1   11      15        3            4
1        1   11      15        5            4
```

Comment: since iloc needs 0-based index, get_indexer must give 0 based index for column, `loc` uses label of index.. so `index[0]` must give label of index at 0 position.. great to know..thanks